# An error has occured. error is: Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 64

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

`An error has occured. error is: Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 64. and stack trace is: Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 64`

18-09-27 09:27:32: (node:25120) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

`Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 64.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:604:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (/usr/local/ddd/ddd/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/ddd/ddd/src/Server/Routes/Routes.js:307:26`

Can't login 
I did

`sudo npm uninstall bcyrpt`

and

`sudo npm install bcrypt`

but I saw same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove npm absolutely and

```
sudo npm install
```

To install modules again then the problem should be solved